# fail to insert into database but no error shown

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with my PHP code. The `insert into..` query does not work, but no connection error is shown. It seems like the function is never called. What am I doing wrong?

```php
function addGroup(){
    require_once('config.php');
    $gid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gid']);
    $sql_add_group="INSERT INTO groups(gid) VALUES(".$gid.");";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_add_group, $link);

    if (! $result) {
       die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($link);
}

if(isset($_POST['Add Group'])){
    addGroup();
}

if($_SESSION['type']=='professor'){   
    echo $_POST['gid'];
    echo('<div>
            <form action="groups.php" method="POST">
              <label>Add/Remove Group<input class = "form-control" type = "text" name = "gid" id = "gid" placeholder = "group#"/></label>
              <input id="button" type="submit" value="Add Group" name="Add Group"> </input>
              <input id="button" type="submit" value="Remove Group" name="Remove Group"> </input>
            </form>
          </div><br/>');
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Your escape call is **NOT** a defence.

Comment: *"but no error shown"* http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php then

Comment: `<input>` elements are self-closing. IDs should be unique.

Comment: According to [php.net](http://php.net/variables.external), "Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores."

Comment: @showdev Thank you, your solution ended up working for me! Also I changed all the require_once to include to make it finally work.